# Solve the following logarithm equation for $x$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Solve the following logarithm equation for $x$.

$2\log_{2}x=3+\log_{2}(x+6)$

I  tried it:

$\log_{2}(x)^2=3+\color{red}{\log_{2}x \cdot \log_{2}6}$

Then, $Let \log_{2}x = y$

$y^2 = 3 +6y$

$y^2 - 6y - 3=0$

Is this right?

Comment: Not quite. In general, $\log(a+b) \not\equiv \log(a) \cdot \log(b)$.

Comment: $2\log_2{x}=\log_2{(x^2)}$, not $\log_2{(x)}^2$

Comment: I would suggest bringing the two logs together and combining, so you can get rid of them both with one two-to-the operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT.** Use these three facts:
$$a=\log_b b^a$$
$$a \log_b x=\log_b x^a$$
$$\log_b(x)+\log_b(y)=\log_b(xy)$$